# Systems of 2 equations in 2 variables: $\sqrt{x}+y=10$ and $x+\sqrt y=5$

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, radicals

I would like to solve the following system:

$$ \sqrt{x}+y=10 \qquad (1)$$

$$ x+\sqrt{y}=5\qquad   (2) $$
I know that this system does not any answer if $ x,y \in \mathbb Z $

Because

by (2)

$\qquad \sqrt{y}=5-x \qquad \Rightarrow\qquad5-x\ge0\qquad \Rightarrow\qquad x\le5$

and by (1)

$\qquad x\ge0$

then

$\qquad 0 \le x\le 5 $

if $X=0\qquad \Rightarrow\qquad y=10,by (1)\qquad x+\sqrt{y}\neq5$

if $X=1\qquad \Rightarrow\qquad y=9,by (1)\qquad x+\sqrt{y}\neq5$

and Similarly, we continue to $X=5$

my question:
Does this system has any answers if $x,y \in \mathbb R ?$

Comment: [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+sqrt%28x%29+%2B+y+%3D+10%2C+y+%2B+sqrt%28x%29+%3D+5) agrees with your conclusion

Comment: You could do it by algebra as well, but I think your way would be more efficient.

Comment: This is not a system of linear equation!

Answer (score 3):

Writing $\sqrt{x}=10-y$, $\sqrt{y}=5-x$ we obtain by squaring
$$
x= y^2 - 20y + 100, \quad y - x^2 + 10x - 25 =0.
$$
Substituting the first equation into the second one gives
$$
 - y^4 + 40y^3 - 590y^2 + 3801y - 9025=0,
$$
which has all roots real. One of these roots leads to a real solution of the original equations, i.e., 
$$
(x,y)=(2.07429337331, 8.5597592655).
$$

Comment: Your last equation have all roots real, but $x$ must be positive, so this is not proof that there are real roots.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But indeed, this is the case for at least one $x$; as you have observed yourself.

Comment: No, you should take the solution as written by Mathematician171 and above. They work.

Comment: Dear Zubin - I checked your polynomial $s^4+s-20s^2+95=0$. It has $4$ real roots. Thanks, by the way.

Comment: @DietrichBurde As it turns out, if you find the [smaller positive root](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=s%5E4%2Bs-20s%5E2%2B95) for $s$ from my polynomial, and subsitute for $s=b=\sqrt{y}$, you get $b^2 = y \approx 8.55$, which matches the solution that you have! You might want to add to your answer the following: $$(x,y) = \left(\left[5-\sqrt{10-\sqrt{5-\sqrt{10-\dots}}} \,\right],\,\,\,\,\,\left[10-\sqrt{5-\sqrt{10-\sqrt{5-\dots }}} \,\right]\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

This system of equations isn't linear because you have square root of a variables. Substituting and simplifyind give us $4$-th degree equation which have only one real root. Approximate value is $(x,y)\approx(2.07429,8.55976)$. Here is the graph of this equations:

[image]

Comment: What polynomial of degree $4$ do you obtain ? Mine has all roots real, namely $y=7.22721301982, y=12.9319100431,
y=11.2811176716, y=8.5597592655$.

Answer (score 0):

From (1) : $x = (10-y)^2$.
From (2): $ y = (5-x)^2$. Thus,

$$x = \left(10-(5-x)^2\right)^2,$$ which is a 4th-degree polynomial. Solve it and test the solutions in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Your equations are not linear because they have a square root. If you put $x = X^2$ and $y = Y^2$, you will transform your set of equations to
\begin{eqnarray*}
X + Y^2 &=& 10 \\
X^2 + Y &=& 5
\end{eqnarray*}
The first of these equations gives $X = 10 - Y^2 \Rightarrow X^2 = 100 - 20Y^2 + Y^4$. On substituting it in the second one, you will get $Y^4 - 20Y^2 + Y + 95 = 0$. This equation can be easily solved numerically, say on http://www.wolframalpha.com.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt x + y = 10$ is part of a parabola symmetric about $y = 10$ with vertex at $(0, 10)$ and $x$ intercept at $(100, 0)$
$x + \sqrt y = 5$ is part a parabola symmetric about $x=5$ axis with vertex $(5, 0)$ and $y_$intercept at $(0,25).$  they intersect at four points in the first quadrant, but the solution is the point in the rectangle $[0,5] \times [0,10]$